# Why WordPress won't allow me to add this DIV in the header of my website or theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In WordPress I'm using a theme called "Fruitful" ([Website](http://themes.fruitfulcode.com/fruitful/)) and it doesn't come with a search bar, so what I'm trying to do here is get the theme to show me a div in the header area so I could put it in search functionality later on; but for some reason it doesn't show up in the browser, not even in the code when I inspect the header in Chrome.

Here's the relevant code which is in a file called header.php:

```
<div class="head-container resp_full_width_menu">
                    <div class="container ">
                        <div class="sixteen columns">
                            <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
                                <?php   
                                    if (fruitful_is_social_header()) { 
                                        fruitful_get_socials_icon(); 
                                    }    
                                ?>
                                <div data-originalstyle="<?php echo $logo_pos_class; ?>" class="header-hgroup <?php echo $logo_pos_class; ?>">  
                                    <?php echo fruitful_get_logo(); ?>
                                </div>  
                                <div data-originalstyle="<?php echo $menu_pos_class; ?>" class="menu-wrapper <?php echo $menu_pos_class; ?>">
                                    <?php fruitful_get_languages_list(); ?>
                                    <?php fruitful_get_cart_button_html(); ?>

                                    <nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">
                                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
                                    </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
                                </div>

                                <div id="search_main"></div>
                            </header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
```

At the very bottom you can observe the div that I added (search_main), I already coded some CSS in style.css just to test if it would show up.. but nothing. I tried deleting header.php and it messes up the site, so that means that file is the right file.

Any ideas on what's going on here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check is there any catching plugin installed or not if its there then just deactivate that and check.